# PyQt4 Toolbar Button Alignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qtgui

I have this code

```
    Menu = self.menuBar()
    EditMenu = Menu.addMenu("&File")
    OptionMenu = Menu.addMenu("&Options")
    HelpMenu = Menu.addMenu("&Help")
    EditMenu.addActions((fileNewAction,faultAction,storeAction,localAction,scheduleAction))
    OptionMenu.addAction(settingAction)

    Toolbar = QtGui.QToolBar()
    Toolbar.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50,50))
    Toolbar.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading) #<= Toolbuttonstyle
    self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.LeftToolBarArea,Toolbar)
    Toolbar.addActions((fileNewAction,faultAction,scheduleAction,storeAction,localAction,settingAction))
    settings = QtCore.QSettings()
    self.restoreGeometry(settings.value("Geometry").toByteArray())
```

which give me this

[image]

i used

```
Toolbar.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading)
```

to display the text on the right side of the toolbar button and to align all the toolbar button images to the left. But the texts are not appearing on the right side.

If i remove the `QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading`,

I get unaligned (left side) buttons like this

[image]

(1) How do i get my toolbar button icons align to the left and display the text on the right side at the same time?

Another question is

(2) How do i adjust the width of the `raised button` effect when i mouse over on each button? I want the width of all the buttons to be the same. The width seems to be different depending on how long the text is.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the problem is the QToolBar decides on a size of each button individually, disregarding neighboring buttons completely. But you can set the size manually:

```
for action in my_toolbar.actions():
    widget = my_toolbar.widgetForAction(action)
    widget.setFixedSize(width, height)
```